# Using Python Cryptography module to encrypt recursively

Tags: python, cryptography

The following code is using the pyAesCrypt module. I would like to achieve the same recursive encryption using the standard Cryptography module. I have tried to read through the documentation for Cryptography, but I can't find a thorough explanation of how to feed it the kind of input on line 21:

```
import pyAesCrypt

import glob
import os
# Encryption/decryption buffer size - 64K
bufferSize = 64 * 1024
# Get current directory
currentdirectory = os.getcwd()
# Prompt user for password to encrypt files
password1 = input('\n> Enter password to encrypt: ')
 
print('\n> Beginning recursive encryption...\n\n')
# Main loop to encrypt all files recursively
for x in glob.glob('./test', recursive=True):
    fullpath = os.path.join(curDir, x)
    fullnewf = os.path.join(curDir, x + '.aes')
    # Encrypt
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
        print('>>> Original: \t' + fullpath + '')
        print('>>> Encrypted: \t' + fullnewf + '\n')
        pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(fullpath, fullnewf, password1, bufferSize)
```

Can anyone help me with how to replace the final line of pyAesCrypt code with code from the Cryptography module?

Comment: the Cryptography module supports Fernet encryption which is different from AES. If you want to use Fernet encryption then you'll have to change more than the final line.

Answer (score 0):

the module uses itself cryptography so you can have a look yourself:
https://github.com/marcobellaccini/pyAesCrypt/blob/master/pyAesCrypt/crypto.py

I wouldn't consider myself a crypto expert but I would not consider this implementation as secure.

- They implement their own Key-Derivation-Function instead of PBKDF2HMAC or SCyrpt (as mentioned in the cryptography docs https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#using-passwords-with-fernet)
- They implement the padding on their own instead of the cryptography functions (but their implementation seems okay...)
- The file-standard seems to expect certain conditions which are not clearly stated. The KDF is not part of the file, the AES mode is not defined... I expect that this "file-standard" is mostly compatible with other implementations of the same author...

No real red flags but a strange feeling in my gut...

If you want to hide something from your little sister it seems fine, if you're up against sophisticated attackers use something different... And if you want to decrypt stuff in the future, keep a copy of the module since the implementation does not seem to be interoperable with other software.